# Ajax is not calling the webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get this loadResources function to work so I have put it behind the call of a button - the function is called but the ajax always fail (i get the "loading of Engineers failed!" alert) and I can't work out why

```
loadResources = function (instructionID) {

    var objResource = {};

    objResource.instructionID = instructionID;
    objResource.ignorePostcode = true;
    objResource.pageIndex = 1;
    objResource.pageSize = 10;
    objResource.totalRows = 0;

    var requestResource = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "NewJob.aspx/getResourcesDayShift",
        data: JSON.stringify(objResource),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
    requestResource.done(function (data) {

        alert(data);

    });
    requestResource.fail(function () {
        //$.unblockUI();
        alert('loading of Engineers failed!');
    });
}
```

this is the method I am trying to call:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string getResourcesDayShift(Guid instructionID, bool ignorePostcode, int pageIndex, int pageSize, ref int totalRows)
    {
        return "blah";

    }
```

Comment: Which http status did you get?

Comment: you need to return back json not string, check your url if is corect

Comment: Remove JSON.stringify and replace it with the just objResource as @madalinivascu pointed.

Comment: done but still not working

Comment: in the asp page return a json

Comment: _Message: "Cannot convert object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int32&'"_ why you need `ref` parameter?

Comment: @Grundy thank you! it was the totalRows int - i will do that another way - if you want to put it in an answer, I will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call this method you get next error message

> Message: "Cannot convert object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int32&'"

This problem with *ref* parameters of your method.

If you want return some data, you can do next change

```
[WebMethod]
public static object getResourcesDayShift(Guid instructionID, bool ignorePostcode, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalRows)//return ref keyword
{
    return new { value = "blah", totalRows=totalRows+1 };

}
```

and on client side you get

```
requestResource.done(function (data) {

    console.log(data.d); //Object {value: "blah", totalRows: 1}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is always pass by value.  So passing reference parameters to your web method is not valid..

In javascript convert the Guid into a string array object and pass that string array object to the web method.

On  your client side.

```
var ie = ['11111111 - 1111 - 1111 - 1111 - 111111111112','14897bf4-f5d0-4548-a74d-a34f00ae9cad'];
 var objResource = { instructionID: ie, ignorePostcode: true, pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 10, totalRows: 0 };



 [WebMethod]
  public static string getResourcesDayShift(string[] instructionID, bool ignorePostcode, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalRows)
        {
            return "blah";

        }
```